# Tutorial to Publish Microsoft LCDS Content To LMS and Track User Interaction

Tags: asp.net, scorm

I want to build an LMS using Microsoft LCDS to publish SCORM compliant contents. This system should be able to track all user interactions, time spent for each modules, course completion percentage, quiz answers and record them in database and then display the details in course report just like Microsoft E-Learning.

Is there any way to do this? I can't find any tutorials how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft LCDS is based on SCORM 1.2. The following link provides you a documentation containing all of the technical requirements about SCORM 1.2, including both LMSs and authoring tools.

http://www.adlnet.gov/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/SCORM_1_2_pdf.zip